# client server side in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, client-server

I have developed a game in JavaScript, now i want to play this game on Network (Client Server). What API or anything should i use to it?

thanks!

Comment: uhm... there is definitely more information needed! ...when you have developed the game already, you don`t need anymore APIs ;)

Comment: Depends on how the game works, your only real option is AJAX but if you need fast response rather than polling you'll need to use pipelining or some such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use Node.js on the server side. It´s really easy to learn & when you have JavaScript on the client-side it fits absolutely perfect!

There is a project named "socket.io" which handles WebSockets, long polling etc for you! It´s quite brilliant!

Check it out ;)

Comment: then there in no need of using these languages like asp.net, PHP ?

Comment: no. If you have skills in JavaScript & have a server where you have root access, it´s easy to do it with node.js. It´s really good in handling thousands of connections with as less resources as possible. It´s really worth the try!!

Comment: I have Tic Tac Toe game code in JavaScript. now i want to run it over Network, means players from two different PC, one clicks and other is waiting, does this node.js suits me to do this.?

Comment: unable to run the server of it. can you please tell me details of it, how to run server and use this?

Comment: What do you mean with "the server of it"? Have you installed node.js on your server? I'll help you, but I need some more information ;)

Comment: I am trying to run the server of "socket.io" on my windows machine, its mentioned on socket.io docs.

Comment: i was trying to run the examples in socket.io project, there i set the folder path of socket.io in server.js file, then by running chat.html,  there is an error in JavaScript, "Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined"

Comment: Did you include the socket.io script on the client side?